# mysql select for checking if a entry exist

Tags: php, mysql

i had a large databse and had to chec if a email is in a special group
I had to tables.

first tabel called user

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  uid int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  kid int(3) NOT NULL,
  Email varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (uid),
  KEY kid (kid)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

and a table named group

```
CREATE TABLE `group` (
  `vuid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `vid` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vuid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

and for every insert i had a defined vid and a email
Now i had to check, if a user with the uid is in the group vid.

`select a.email,b.vuid from user a, group b where a.email=\''.$email.'\' and a.kid=' . $kid.' and b.vid=' . $vid . ' and a.uid = b.uid limit 1')`

and check if the mysql_fetch_assoc is true or false.

BUT this is verry verry slow. is there a simple way to speed up ?

Comment: Why are you checking the email as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a comma separated list of tables, try using a `JOIN` (in this case, [`INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) is your best bet since you want to check if records exist in both tables) with an `ON` clause.  I have formatted your query and my changes are in capitals to make them stand out.

```
select 
    a.email,
    b.vuid 
from 
    user a
    INNER JOIN group b 
        ON a.uid = b.uid
where 
    a.email=\''.$email.'\' 
    and a.kid=' . $kid.' 
    and b.vid=' . $vid . ' 
limit 1
```

Next, check your indexes - make sure you have indexes on b.uid and a.kid.  As a general rule, check your where clauses for values you can index; anything with unique values is a candidate.

Answer (score 1):

If its slow, you might be missing indexes on either the lookup column or on the foreign key column.

Comment: Any column that you are using as a foreign key should be defined the same as the key in the foreign table and have an index. This way Mysql can handle the join quickly. If you don't do that, it will have to use slower table scan methods to join the tables.

Comment: :-/ could you please help me ? like ALTER TABLE group ADD FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES user(uid) ??

Comment: You dont need to add foreign key constraints, you just need to add indexes.

Comment: does i have to restartv the db ? because it istn faster... think slower

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
ALTER TABLE `group` ADD INDEX `uid`(uid);
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD INDEX `email`(`Email`);
```

This should fix your slowness.